# I'm having issues with an API

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I'm having issues with getting this API to work.

I have used the same code with Google Finance API and that works perfectly. The issue is that I can only get a small amount of stocks out, and in the long run, I need to run 12000 stocks through (if possible).

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var temp = [];
    $(document).ready(function(){
        stockInformation();
        setInterval(stockInformation, 5000);
    });
    function stockInformation()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"https://api.website.com/public/user/token/stock/SDRL/quote",
            dataType:"jsonp",
            jsonp:"callback",
            jsonpCallback:"quote"
        });
        var i = 0; var j = 0;var status = "";
        quote = function(data){
            var output = "<table>"
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                if (value.l_cur > temp[j])
                    status = "<td style=color:green>Up</td>";
                else if (value.l_cur < temp[j])
                    status = "<td style=color:red>Down</td>";
                else
                    status = "<td>Same</td>";
                j++;
                output += "<tr><td>" + value.t + "</td><td>" + value.l_cur + "</td>" + status + "</tr>";
                temp[i] = value.l_cur;i++;
            })
            output += "</table>";
            $("#result").html(output);
        }
    }
</script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

This is what the API returns (not with the code above):

```
{"timestamp":"1503691321","datetime":"2017-08-25 16:02:01 (UTC)","price":"6.17","price change":"0.12","price pct change":"1.98","open":"6.09","volumn":"1852887","low":"6.00","high":"6.22","currency":"USD"}
```

Comment: So then the problem is with the API itself? How can we possibly help you with that?

Comment: More than likely the api is going to have some time of rate limiting on it, 12,000 is quite a few requests to do in a small time. You should look through the API's documentation to see if it has options for specifying the number of items you want to receive in one request, or how to request multiple quotes

Comment: That didn't work.. :/ the API has a problem that will only return 1 result back even if i try to loop different symbols through the ticker spot in the url. I'm sure there is no limit with this api.

Comment: Sounds like you need to take this up with the people who host that API endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Many of googles api's limit the number of requests you can make in a given amount of time. Sometimes even as low as 50 per month depending on the api and the type of request. Its doesn't look like there is anything wrong with the way you are using the api in your code. 
You could get around that though potentially by paginating. Start with like 30 at a time then when your user clicks a next button or scrolls to the end of the page then go get the next 30.